# Should a semicolon be used before both a coordinating conjunction and a conjunctive adverb?

Tags: orthography, punctuation

Please see: http://academics.smcvt.edu/writingctr/semicolons.htm for reference.

Now I understand that a semicolon could be used before a conjunctive adverb (eg: also, furthermore, therefore, etc..) but not before a coordinating conjunction (eg: and, or, but, etc..), but how about using it before both of them?

Examples:

1. My hobbies include being a couch potato, eating lots of food **; and accordingly,** sleeping.
2. He can use English to speak, write **; and hence, read.**

*P.S. Please excuse the extra space before the semicolons in my examples.*

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon is extremely odd there. It feels like the sort of thing someone would write who wasn't experienced.

In both cases, I would eschew the middle comma:

> My hobbies include being a couch potato, eating lots of food and, accordingly, sleeping.
>   He can use English to speak, write and, hence, read.

This violates the supposed "Oxford comma" rule, of course, but despite what *The New Yorker* might think, sometimes less is more. (And note that there is certainly no "Oxford semicolon" rule.)

Note also that the adverbs you're talking about here are not conjunctive. They are used parenthetically.